# Sequelize error using association on n:m related objects

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using nodeJS, express (4.17.1), sequelize (5.21.4) and mysql (mysql2 v2.1.0) for a current project.

In my database I have three tables Filter, Element and FilterElement. If I query data from database from Filter or Element table separatly I get the result of objects with data. If I want to use "connecting" table FilterElement I get this error **{"name":"SequelizeEagerLoadingError"}**

> EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: filter_element is not
>   associated to filters_new!

What is wrong with my code?
These are my sequelize objects codes.

Filter.js

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/database');

const Filter = db.define('filters_new', {
    Model:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    }
},
    {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true
    }
);


Filter.associate = function(models) {
    Filter.belongsToMany(models.Element, {
      through: models.FilterElement,
      as: 'filter',
      foreignKey: 'FilterHousingModel'
    });
  };


module.exports = Filter;
```

Element.js

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/database');

const Element = db.define('filter_element', {
    idfilter_element:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    ElementName:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    }  
},
    {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true
    }
);



Element.associate = function(models) {
    Element.belongsToMany(models.Filter, {
      through: models.FilterElement,
      as: 'element',
      foreignKey: 'FilterElementId'
    });
  };


module.exports = Element;
```

FilterElemnt.js

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/database');

const FilterElement = db.define('filters_new', {
    idfilter_filterelement:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoincrement: true
    },
    FilterHousingModel: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    FilterElementId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER        
    }
},
    {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true
    }
);



module.exports = FilterElement;
```

If I call this function, I do get the desired result of data from database.

```js
listFiltersOnly(req, res) {
    
        return filter.findAll()
        .then((filters) => { 
            res.status(200).send(filters);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400).send(err);
        });
    }
```

then if I call function list I get the error mentioned up **EagerLoadingError**

```js
list(req, res) {
        return filter.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: element,
                as: 'element'
            }],
        })
        .then((filters) => { 
            console.log(filters);
            res.status(200).send(filters);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400).send(err);
        });
    }
```

Looking for some suggjestions where might be the problem?

Comment: I couldn’t find any reference for ‘Model.associate’ in sequelize V5 reference. What i see and know is using assocation function like ‘belongsTo’, ‘hasMany’ these directly. Did you call Model.associate manually within your implementation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RatulSharker I removed the asociation from the model and added it where the models are implemented in the controller and now I do get some results.

```js
Filter.belongsToMany(FilterElement, {
    through: FilterFilterElement,
    foreignKey: 'FilterHousingModel'
});


FilterElement.belongsToMany(Filter, {
    through: FilterFilterElement,
    foreignKey: 'FilterElementId'
});
```

Thank you @Ratul Sharker